# extending cxGrid with cxgridDbTableview

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tcxgrid

I have created a component by extending cxGrid  and added some required properties, I want to do same and add some extra functionalities to cxGridDBTableView, 
I tried extending the cxGridDBTableView and added properties, but I am not able to access those properties because when i drop my TdxdmGrid It is using the default cxgridTableView but I want to use TdxdmGridDbtableView,

I tried like below, But it is showing 2 different components and the view I designed is not linked to the grid.
[image]

How can this be achieved?
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Address your question to DevEx support. They are very helpful and will tell you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: **Please** don't post source code as screenshots! SO has an "Insert code" functionality for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You must register View with `cxGridRegisteredViews`, not with `RegisterComponets()`
2. If you want TDXPDMGridDBTableView as default View you must override `TcxGrid.GetDefaultViewClass()`. DefaultView is View which is created when you put your Grid to Form

```pascal
  TDXPDMGrid = class(TcxGrid)
    ...
    protected
      function GetDefaultViewClass: TcxCustomGridViewClass; override;
    ...
  end;
...
function TDXPDMGrid.GetDefaultViewClass: TcxCustomGridViewClass;
begin
  Result := TDXPDMGridDBTableView;
end;
...
initialization
  cxGridRegisteredViews.Register(TDXPDMGridDBTableView, 'PDM Table');
...
finalization
  cxGridRegisteredViews.Unregister(TDXPDMGridDBTableView);
```